# Scraping the metadata of 10,000 website is too slow (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, metadata

Hi all,

I'm trying to parse the metadata of 10,000 websites into a Pandas dataframe for an SEO / analytics application but the code is taking ages. I've been trying to do it on 1,000 websites and the code has been running for the last 3 hours (it works without problem on 10-50 websites).

Here's the sample data:

```
index   site    
0       http://www.google.com
1       http://www.youtube.com
2       http://www.facebook.com
3       http://www.cnn.com
...     ...
10000   http://www.sony.com
```

Here's my Python (2.7) code:

```
# Importing dependencies
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import metadata_parser

# Loading the Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('final_urls')

# Utility functions
def meta(website, metadata):
    full_url = website
    parser = metadata_parser.MetadataParser(url=full_url)
    if metadata == 'all':
        return parser.metadata
    else:
        return parser.metadata[metadata]

def meta_all(website):
    try:
        result = meta(website, 'all')
    except BaseException:
        result = 'Exception'
    return result

# Main
df['site'].apply(meta_all)
```

I'd like the code to be much faster. I've been using the `metadata_parser` library (https://github.com/jvanasco/metadata_parser) which relies heavily on `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

- I understand I might be able to change the parser to `lxml` for the code to be faster. It's already installed on my machine so `BeautifulSoup` should use it as the primary choice.
- Do you have any suggestion to get this code to run faster?

Thanks!

Comment: `df.apply` sequentially calls your function for every website. You would benefit from having every request be sent in parallel, which I don't think pandas supports.

Comment: that's true and I can do that analysis outside and import it back - what do you suggest to implement this in parallel? Using the built-in `multiprocessing` library?

Comment: I haven't used it, but maybe you can find something useful in this library: https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/

Comment: If your app is IO bound (most time spent to download pages) you should rework your app to play with threading, multiprocessing, or async processing (requires Python 3.4 or later).

Comment: I never tried it but there is [GRequest = Requests + Gevent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests). From doc: `"GRequests allows you to use Requests with Gevent to make asynchronous HTTP Requests easily."`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python Twisted (Twisted is an event-driven networking engine written in Python). You will need to install a few packages with pip, maybe twisted, pyopenssl and service_identity maybe others. This code works on Python 2.7 which you say you are using.

```
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.web.client import getPage
import metadata_parser
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process

def pageCallback(result, url):
    data = {
        'content': result,
        'url': url,
    }
    return data

def getPageData(url):
    d = getPage(url)
    d.addCallback(pageCallback, url)
    return d

def listCallback(result):
    for isSuccess, data in result:
        if isSuccess:
            print("Call to %s succeeded " % (data['url']))
            parser = metadata_parser.MetadataParser(html=data['content'], search_head_only=False)
            print(parser.metadata)  # do something with it here

def finish(ign):
    reactor.stop()

def start(urls):
    data = []
    for url in urls:
        data.append(getPageData(url))
    dl = defer.DeferredList(data)
    dl.addCallback(listCallback)
    dl.addCallback(finish)

def processStart(chunk):
    start(chunk)
    reactor.run()

df = pd.read_csv('final_urls')
urls = df['site'].values.tolist()
chunkCounter = 0
chunkLength = 1000
for chunk in np.array_split(urls,len(urls)/chunkLength):
    p = Process(target=processStart, args=(chunk,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    chunkCounter += 1
    print("Finished chunk %s of %s URLs" % (str(chunkCounter), str(chunkLength)))
```

I have run it on 10,000 URLs and it took less than 16 minutes.

**Updated**
Normally you would process the data you generated where I added the comment "# do something with it here". In the event you want the generated data returned back for processing you can do something like this (I have also updated to use treq.):

```
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
import treq
import metadata_parser
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from twisted.python import log
import sys

# log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

results = []

def pageCallback(result, url):
    content = result.content()
    data = {
    'content': content,
    'url': url,
    }
    return data

def getPageData(url):
    d = treq.get(url, timeout=60, headers={'User-Agent': ["Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv'\:'57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"]})
    d.addCallback(pageCallback, url)
    return d

def listCallback(result):
    global results
    for isSuccess, data in result:
        if isSuccess:
            print("Call to %s succeeded " % (data['url']))
            parser = metadata_parser.MetadataParser(html=str(data['content']), search_head_only=False)
            # print(parser.metadata)  # do something with it here
            results.append((data['url'], parser.metadata))

def finish(ign):
    reactor.stop()

def start(urls):
    data = []
    for url in urls:
        data.append(getPageData(url))
    dl = defer.DeferredList(data)
    dl.addCallback(listCallback)
    dl.addCallback(finish)

def processStart(chunk, returnList):
    start(chunk)
    reactor.run()
    returnList.extend(results)

df = pd.read_csv('final_urls')
urls = df['site'].values.tolist()
chunkCounter = 0
chunkLength = 1000

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
returnList = manager.list()
for chunk in np.array_split(urls,len(urls)/chunkLength):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=processStart, args=(chunk,returnList))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    chunkCounter += 1
    print("Finished chunk %s of %s URLs" % (str(chunkCounter), str(chunkLength)))

for res in returnList:
    print (res)

print (len(returnList))
```

You may also want to add some error handling, to help you can uncomment the line reading "log.startLogging(sys.stdout)" but this is too much detail for one answer. If you get some failures for URLs I would generally retry them by running the code again with just the failed URLs possibly a few times if necessary.

Comment: I updated my original answer as on my machine it broke with somewhere over 1,000 URLs at a time. I have now split the URLs into chunks of 1,000 which get parsed in a separate process as you can nor restart the reactor. You may need to fiddle around with the value of chunkLength to get it to work in other environments.

Comment: Thanks I've been trying to run this but I'm not getting any particular output. The code seems to breeze through the urls in no time (5 sec) but I'm not able to access the data dictionary that's being populated (original urls and json of the metadata). I think I don't know enough about the twisted library to really understand what's happening + I get a deprecated error when I run it: `DeprecationWarning: twisted.web.client.getPage was deprecated in Twisted 16.7.0; please use https://pypi.org/project/treq/ or twisted.web.client.Agent instead app.launch_new_instance()`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: To change it to a dictionary start by changing to manager.dict()